# UIImageView, animate animationImages with easeIn easeInOut transition

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uiimageview, transition

I have a code:

```
NSArray * imageArray  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"11.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"12.png"],
                            nil];
    UIImageView * imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
        CGRectMake(100, 125, 150, 130)];
    imgView.animationImages = imageArray;
    imgView.animationDuration = 2;
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottomLeft;
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
    [imgView startAnimating];
```

As you see, this code implements animation (change) of collection of images in imageArray.
During animation, each image changes with constant time interval, lets say it animates with easeNone transition.

**But, How can I make this animation with easeIn, easeInOut transition?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, It's been a year since this has been posted.

I'm unsure if you have found your answer, but what I have done is made the easing myself through the Images  (1.png, 2.png.. etc.)

For example:

PNG's `1-5.png` may have 10px spacing between the animated item.

PNG's `6-8.png` may have 5px spacing between the animated item.

PNG's `9-10.png` may have 2px spacing between the animated item.

finally
PNG's `9-10.png` may have 1px spacing between the animated item, or no spacing difference at all.

Doing this will give you the *Ease Out* effect you're looking for.

### **Trial and Error is the Key!**

What I like to do is set-up my animation in Xcode (like what you have done in your Question), then move over to Photoshop and overwrite the `PNG`'s in my development folder, try them in the Simulator, and repeat until I get the desired effect.

Comment: Hi. 1 year later, I didn't implement this task, because I don't need it anymore) Your logic is clear, It actually explains how easing animation is working. Do you have working example?